# Markov Random Fields vs Hidden Markov Model

Tags: hidden-markov-model, markov-random-field

I'm kinda new to these topics, I wanted to know if there are any relations between those two topics, Markov Random Fields and Hidden Markov Models (Markov Chains). I feel like they are completely different from each other, though in some sources people tend to say they are related.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are similar in the sense that they are both graphical models, i.e., both of them describe a factorization of a joint distribution according to some graph structure. However, Markov Random Fields are undirected graphical models (i.e., they describe a factorization of a Gibbs distribution in terms of the clique potentials of some underlying graph). Hidden Markov Models, on the other hand, are a subclass of directed graphical models (i.e., they describe a factorization in terms of a product of conditional probability distributions) with a specific structure that describes some dynamic process with long-term dependencies. Both types of models can be converted into so-called factor graphs, so that the same algorithms can be used to perform inference tasks in them (e.g., compute marginal distributions or a MAP estimate).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It clarified the relation between them.

Answer (score 3):

Hidden Markov Models can be represented as directed graphs (with Bayesian Networks, letter a) of image below) or as undirected graphs (with Markov Random Fields, letter b) of image below, [link here](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/titles/content/9780262015776_sch_0001.pdf)).

[image]

So yes, you can use Markov Random Fields to represent an HMM.